# How to web scrape Rotowire table

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

While inspecting the site I can't locate the slateID.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://www.rotowire.com/daily/tables/optimizer-mlb.php'
payload = {
'siteID': '1',
'slateID': '6441',
'projSource': 'RotoWire',
'rst': 'RotoWire'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData)
```

OUTPUT

```
print(df)
        id playerID rotoPlayerID  ... ie_green_lights ie_matchup_notes ie_volatility
0    12739    11095        12739  ...               0                              0
1    10510     4081        10510  ...               0                              0
2    16036     5163        16036  ...               0                              0
3    14194    10827        14194  ...               0                              0
4    14865    15463        14865  ...               0                              0
..     ...      ...          ...  ...             ...              ...           ...
687  14444    11330        14444  ...               0                              0
688  14440    18894        14440  ...               0                              0
689  14439    18905        14439  ...               0                              0
690  14435     5058        14435  ...               0                              0
691  17921    18828        17921  ...               0                              0
```

website has changed and I can no long find the daily slateid.

Answer (score 0):

This is API implementation issue. Here get() is not returning that column thats why you are not able to locate.

```
    url = 'https://www.rotowire.com/daily/tables/optimizer-mlb.php'
payload = {
'siteID': '1',
'slateID': '6441',
'xxx':'123',
'projSource': 'RotoWire',
'rst': 'RotoWire'}
jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData)
df
```

If you consider above example I added a key value pair in parameters 'xxx':'123'. Still result is same. Which means only meaningful parametrs are being considered and fixed formated output is returned.
API does not return slateID filed in its output.

Comment: How to scrap the table on rotowire.com/daily/mlb/optimizer.php